# Angular deploy to readme page

Tags: angular, deployment, github-pages

I have deployed a my angular project to my github page like "myusername.github.io".
I run the project with these commands:

```
ng build --prod --base-href="https://<username>.github.io/<repo>/"

ngh --dir=dist/<angular project name>
```

When completed, it show me readme page.
I tried many ways to learn from the 'Stack' but still not.
Here's my repos: https://github.com/gladdental/gladdental.github.io
Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure if `ngh` deploys to github page. You can try `https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages`

Comment: from which folder you are serving github pages?

Comment: It's from 'path_to\gdentaladmin\gladdental.github.io>'